# Commerce checkout price calculation

Tags: commerce

Hi I have a problem with commerce checkout, which calculates wrong total prices.

My local dev site, which was created using commerce kickstarter 1.33, calculates the prices correctly including all taxes.
My demo site, on which I installed all modules manually, doens't add the taxes.

Since I exported all my tax configurations and some other componentes via features, the configuration should be the same, but maybe I'm missing a hidden configuration?

The problem seems to be, that the rules event "Calculating the sell price of a product" doesn't fire on my demo site, since it does fire on my dev site.

Commerce Kickstart doesn't seem to use any additional modules like [Commerce price by components](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_components) and I didn't install any other modules to my dev site either.

Has anyone experienced this odd behavior?

Comment: Currently there is a known problem with commerce and the latest rules module https://www.drupal.org/node/2324587. Price calculation should be fine if you downgrade to rules 2.7. Can you test that? I also do believe the patch has been committed to dev, so you might try latest development release as well.